# Integrating function over region is slow

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I have a function

```
f[pt_] := Log[1/(1 - Abs[x])] + Log[1/(1 - Abs[y])] /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}
```

That looks like this:

[image]

I want to integrate it over a rotated rectangle:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[f[{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] 
     TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}], 
         RotationTransform[theta]]], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

But it's very slow, and I keep getting errors like:

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration
is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

I don't think this function should be that difficult to integrate.

I tried to rotate it myself like this:

```
r[t_] := {{Cos[t], -Sin[t]}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}}
Plot[NIntegrate[f[r[theta].{x, y}], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

But it is still very slow. As in I had to kill it after multiple minutes of no results.
I'm using Mathematica 12.1.1.0.
Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

---

Bonus problem:
I also want to find the maximum of the function.
So I take

```
FindMaximum[{NIntegrate[f[r[theta].{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}]], 0 <= theta <= 2 Pi}, {theta, .1}]
```

However, this gives me a bunch of errors like

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand g[x Cos[theta]-y Sin[theta],
y Cos[theta]+x Sin[theta]] has evaluated to non-numerical values
for all sampling points in the region with boundaries
{{-(1/2),0.},{-(1/2),1/2}}.
```

I tried to change the definition of `r` to

```
r[t_?NumericQ] := {{Cos[t], -Sin[t]}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}}
```

But it doesn't seem to improve things. It only changes the error to

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand g[r[theta],{x,y}] has evaluated to
non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with
boundaries {{-(1/2),1/2},{-(1/2),1/2}}.
```

Note that the function is definitely defined at this location, and for all valid points in the region for any rotation.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Work fine in v13.1

Comment: @cvgmt I just tried on Mathematica Online (which I presume is v13) and the plots are still very slow, while the Maximization still gives "non-numerical values" errors. (Though it doesn't find a result.)

Answer (score 5):

We can also fix the integral region but transform the function by `RotationMatrix`.

```
f[{x_, y_}] = Log[1/(1 - Abs[x])] + Log[1/(1 - Abs[y])];
Plot[NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[f[{x, y} . RotationMatrix[θ]]], {x, -1/2, 
   1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
int[θ_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  f[{x, y} . RotationMatrix[θ]] // Evaluate, {x, -1/2, 
   1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}]
FindMaximum[{int[θ], 0 <= θ <= 2 π}, {θ, .1}]
```

[image]

> `{0.613705, {θ -> 0.00170899}}`

Comment: Is the trick here the use of `// Evaluate` or the `?NumericQ` in `int`? It's still not intuitive for me when to use what

Comment: @ThomasAhle The `?NuericQ` skill for `FindMaximum`, and the `Evaluate` is not necessary, the main ideas is using the integral transformation, avoid transform the domain.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[pt_] := Total[Log[1/(1 - Abs[#])] & /@ pt]

rgn[theta_] = 
  TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}], 
    RotationTransform[theta]] // Simplify;

int[theta_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[{x, y}], {x, y} ∈ rgn[theta]]

Plot[int[theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
({max, arg} = FindMaximum[int[theta], {theta, 1.6}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.1356, {0.613706, {theta -> 1.57082}}} *)
```

Comment: What is the whole trick with `Total` and `&/@`?

Comment: Each of the terms in your function is just the pure function `Log[1/(1 - Abs[#])] &` evaluated with the parts of `pt`. So the pure function is mapped ( `/@` ) onto the elements of `pt`. Then the `Total` adds terms to produce the result. See the documentation for `Function`, `Map`, `Total`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. Do you think there's anything I can do to speed up the function? As you've shown, currently plotting takes nearly a minute. Is there maybe a way to use NDSolve instead of NumericalIntegrate?